# Highchart Color Issue for series with single data with multiple colors

Tags: javascript, css, graph, charts, highcharts

I was working on my chart,But it gives only single color for a **`name:vengadesh`** ,

Here is my  Chart code in Fiddle..

[**My Example Chart in FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7VNwk/)

But i want to get multiple colors for a single person dynamically...

**My Actual Chart**
[image]

**MY EXPECTED CHART**
[image: **MY EXPECTED CHART**]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution is to set array of colors for series, then set `colorByPoint: true`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/7VNwk/2/

```
        series: [{
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Vengadesh',
            data: [2, 2, 2],
            colors: ['blue', 'red', 'green'],
            colorByPoint: true

        }]
```

Comment: FUS: I have a small doubt, In this example , if i want to remove Average,High & Low in tooltip means , what i want to do??

Comment: Fus: A Big Thanks for u Friend... Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
series: [{
type: 'column',
name: 'Member Average Packer Price',
data: [{y: 110.20, color: 'red'},     // this point is red
                           // default blue
      {y: 110.20, color: '#aaff99'}, // this will be greenish
     ],
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7VNwk/1/)